# Flex item's auto margin cuts parent's padding

Tags: html, css

When item's (`#box`) height is bigger than screen, parent container's (`#wrap`) bottom padding gets cut off.

[image]

Normal view, `#wrap`'s bottom and top padding applied:

[image]

```css
html, body {
  
    height: 100%;
  
}

#wrap {
  
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  
}

#box {
  
    padding: 20px;
    background: red;
    margin: auto;
  
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">

<div id="box">
CONTENT
<br>
CONTENT
<br>
CONTENT
<br>CONTENT
<br>
CONTENT
<br>
CONTENT
<br>
CONTENT
<br>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Try to use margin instead of padding

Comment: No padding cut, it is margin cut. Try usin margin, as Awais said.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```css
        html {
            height: 100%;
        }
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            height: 100%;
        }
        #wrap {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 20px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            height: 100%;
        }
        #box {
            padding: 20px;
            background: red;
            margin: 20px auto;
        }
```

```html
    <div id="wrap">
        <div id="box">
            CONTENT
            <br> CONTENT
            <br> CONTENT
            <br> CONTENT
            <br> CONTENT
            <br> CONTENT
            <br> CONTENT
            <br>
        </div>
    </div>
```